# Php extra HREF using DOMXPATH

Tags: php, domdocument

```
<a class="_tr" href="/shopping/product/4889160295225917760/reviews?q=0028400047906&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiHjMGfo8_UAhUU5mMKHSK2BYUQvCQIYw">
```

I was trying to just use `$nodeList = $xpath->query("//a[@href]");`

I cant seem to get it to work, I just need the href value which I will later parse to extra `4889160295225917760` from it

When echoing the above I can an empty screen

heres what I got

```
<?php
$page = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/search?q=0028400047906');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($page);   
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$test = $xpath->query('//a[@class="_tr"]');
$href = $test->item(0)->getAttribute("href");
echo explode("/", $href)[3];
?>`
```

I was doing some testing and took it back to step #1, figured out that file_get_contents retrieves nothing from google search results, its an empty screen

Comment: Show full code please.

Comment: It doesn't allow me to paste full code but if you could please take a look at this link: https://www.google.com/search?q=0028400047906 and help me out I would really appriciate it, thanks!

Comment: Do you want to get all IDs from `href` ?

Comment: Yes exactly! I Just cant seem to get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work, I've done a lot with xpath recently->

```
$nodelist = $xpath->evaluate("string(/a/@href)", NULL, FALSE);
```

This works in an xml file, not sure if it works with your html though.

Answer (score 0):

If `file_get_contents('https://...'`) doesn't retrieve anything, it might be because opening external files via URLs is disabled by the runtime configuration setting [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen). You can check its value with `ini_get('allow_url_fopen')`, which should return a truthy value, like `"1"`, if it is enabled, or a falsy value, like `"0"` or an empty string `""`, if it is disabled.

You'll need access to the system-wide `php.ini` (or `httpd.conf`) to change this setting, or contact your system administrator.

If the setting can't be changed you need to use something like [cURL](http://php.net/manual/book.curl.php), to retrieve the contents of the URL.